# Load logback configurations based on environment with Scala Play2.5

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5, configuration-management

I would like to load different logback configurations based on SCALA_ENV environmental variable.

1. if SCALA_ENV=PROD load logback.xml
2. if SCALA_ENV=dev load logback-dev.xml
3. if SCALA_ENV=test load logback-test.xml
4. if SCALA_ENV=qa load logback-qa.xml

From Play2.5 docuemntation i found this example but it is not clear.
     [image]

> Also MyComponenets is unresolved and compilation fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in my `build.sbt` file:

```
// logback for Prod
javaOptions in Production += "-Dlogger.resource=logback.prod.xml"

// logback for testing
javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.resource=logback.test.xml"
```

My default one is the dev, which is just left at the default location.

Comment: hmm this should work temporarily. But what if i want to add another logback for QA (logback.qa.xml) and load logback.qa.xml when SCALA_ENV=QA?

Comment: How to run sbt in production mode ?

Comment: The `javaOptions` just saves you having to specify those on the command line.  If you want to run something else then just do `./myapp/bin/myapp -Dlogger.resource=logback.qa.xml`.  For your second question, you can do `sbt testProd`

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but I'm changed the -Dlogger.resource file based on environment in build.sbt

```
 lazy val logBackXml = sys.env("env").toLowerCase() match {
      case "prod" => "-Dlogger.resource=logback.xml"
      case "test" => "-Dlogger.resource=logback.test.xml"
      case "qa"   => "-Dlogger.resource=logback.qa.xml"
      case _      => "-Dlogger.resource=logback.dev.xml"
 }

 javaOptions in Production += logBackXml
```